# Show status message after long operation

Tags: redirect, splongoperation

I've implemented a custom web part allowing to upload a CSV file which will create list items according to the content of the CSV file.

How it has to behave:

- Specify a CSV file
- On import click: Create the list items according to the CSV content and show a modal dialog during the import process
- On import finish: Stay on the same page and display a status message with the import result

I've tried different approaches:

All of them use following method to display the status message:

```
public static void WriteToStatusBar(ControlCollection controlCollection, string message, bool isError)
{
    SPPageStatusSetter statusBar = new SPPageStatusSetter();
    statusBar.AddStatus(string.Empty, message, isError ? SPPageStatusColor.Red : SPPageStatusColor.Green);
    controlCollection.Add(statusBar);
}
```

**1) Show a modal dialog using javascript during the import operation**

Script to show modal dialog:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showWaitDialog() {
        try {
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('<asp:localize runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:SBB.elBus.General.Resources, ImportAppointmentsWaitHeader %>"/>', '<asp:localize runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:SBB.elBus.General.Resources, ImportAppointmentsWaitMessage %>"/>', 120, 500);
        } catch(ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Import button definition:

```
<asp:Button ID="ImportAppointmentsButton" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:SBB.elBus.General.Resources, ImportAppointmentsControl_ImportAppointmentsButton %>" OnClientClick="javascript:showWaitDialog();" onclick="OnImportDataButtonClick"/>
```

Import button event handler:

```
protected void OnImportDataButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        string message;
        if (ElBusHelper.ImportAppointments(FileUpload.FileContent, out message))
        {
            ElBusHelper.WriteToStatusBar(Controls, message, false);
        }
        else
        {
            ElBusHelper.WriteToStatusBar(Controls, message, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
This works fine, as long as the import operation doesn't last too long and ends up in a `System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out`

**2) Use SPLongOperation instead of js dialog**

Import button definition:

```
<asp:Button ID="ImportAppointmentsButton" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:SBB.elBus.General.Resources, ImportAppointmentsControl_ImportAppointmentsButton %>" onclick="OnImportDataButtonClick"/>
```

Import button event handler:

```
    protected void OnImportDataButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            string message;
            bool importSuccess;

            using (SPLongOperation longOperation = new SPLongOperation(Page))
            {
                longOperation.LeadingHTML = ElBusHelper.GetLocalizedString("ImportAppointmentsWaitHeader");
                longOperation.TrailingHTML = ElBusHelper.GetLocalizedString("ImportAppointmentsWaitMessage");
                longOperation.Begin();

                importSuccess = ElBusHelper.ImportAppointments(FileUpload.FileContent, out message);

                longOperation.End(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/ImportAppointments.aspx?"));
            }
            ElBusHelper.WriteToStatusBar(Controls, message, !importSuccess);
        }
    }
```

Result:
The status message is not being displayed, as the Controls being passed to write the status message are the ones from the source page and not the ones from the page where the long operation redirects to.

**3) Show the status message on page load:**

Import button definition:

```
<asp:Button ID="ImportAppointmentsButton" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:SBB.elBus.General.Resources, ImportAppointmentsControl_ImportAppointmentsButton %>" onclick="OnImportDataButtonClick"/>
```

Import button event handler:

```
protected void OnImportDataButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        string message;
        bool importSuccess;

        using (SPLongOperation longOperation = new SPLongOperation(Page))
        {
            longOperation.LeadingHTML = ElBusHelper.GetLocalizedString("ImportAppointmentsWaitHeader");
            longOperation.TrailingHTML = ElBusHelper.GetLocalizedString("ImportAppointmentsWaitMessage");
            longOperation.Begin();

            importSuccess = ElBusHelper.ImportAppointments(FileUpload.FileContent, out message);

            longOperation.End(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + string.Format("/ImportAppointments.aspx?{0}={1}&{2}={3}",REQUESTPARAM_MESSAGE, message, REQUESTPARAM_SUCCESS, importSuccess));
        }
    }
}
```

Page load event handler:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    // Show status message if required request parameters have been set
    if (Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains(REQUESTPARAM_MESSAGE) && Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains(REQUESTPARAM_SUCCESS))
    {
        string message = Request.Params[REQUESTPARAM_MESSAGE];
        bool success = bool.Parse(Request.Params[REQUESTPARAM_SUCCESS]);
        ElBusHelper.WriteToStatusBar(Controls, message, !success);
    }
}
```

Result:
This works, but ends up in an 'ugly' URL containing the entire message to be displayed.

That's how the status message is being displayed after the import operation:
[image: custom web part with status message]

Constraints: As the application I'm developing will be hosted on a web app with multiple site collections, I'm not allowed to modify the web.config to e.g. increase response timeouts.

**Question**: Is 3) the best approach or can you point me to a 'nicer' solution?

Comment: Could you host a .NET 4.0/4.5 site on the same server? I'm not sure of your architecture/number of users, but this would be perfect for SignalR.

Comment: I'll have to check this with the guys maintaining the environment. Currently we run with .NET 3.5. Thanks for the SignalR tip, I didn't know the library.